# Swift Time always late by 3 hours from real time

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdatecomponents

I have array contains a set of hours time string when I want to change it to date  I got it 3 hours late from the real time.

My date formatter is like below

```
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        formatter.dateStyle = .none
```

```
 startArr = ["5:14 Am","1:07 PM" , "4:41 PM", "7:28 PM", "8:52 PM"]
            let startdateArray = (startArr).map { Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from:formatter.date(from:$0)!) }
            let upcomingDates = startdateArray.map { Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: $0, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!  }

            let nextDate = upcomingDates.sorted().first!
            print("next date", nextDate)
            for (i, n) in startArr.enumerated() {
                print(i, "->", n)
            }
```

I have got the following output from my above snippet

next date 2019-09-10 13:41:00 +0000

0 -> 5:14 AM

1 -> 1:07 PM

2 -> 4:41 PM

3 -> 7:28 PM

4 -> 8:52 PM

Comment: Have you tried setting the formatter to your time zone?

Comment: Try adding this `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC"`.

Comment: yes I tried. But not working

Comment: And did you try setting it for the Calendar?

Comment: After adding `timeZone` what is the output ?

Comment: The date is correct. `print` shows dates always in UTC. `2019-09-10 13:41:00 +0000` and `2019-09-10 16:41:00 +0300` is the same point in time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by making another formatter for print

```
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: localTimeZoneName)
```

and print formatter

```
        let printf = DateFormatter()
        printf.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
        printf.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: localTimeZoneName)
```

and I printed  `nextDate` after converting it to a string using `printf` formatter

```
     print("next date", printf.string(from: nextDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `timeZone` of `DateFormatter` to `TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")`, i.e.

```
let startArr = ["5:14 AM", "1:07 PM", "4:41 PM", "7:28 PM", "8:52 PM"]
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
let datesArray = startArr.compactMap({ formatter.date(from: $0) })
print(datesArray)
```

Comment: it did not dolve the problem

Comment: What issue are you facing with this?